# How to Call a SQLiteOpenHelper Class Having it's name in a String

Tags: class, cursor, sqliteopenhelper

I have several readable databases in my assets, with the same structure. The user will select the name of a database, and the name of its `SQliteOpenHelper` class is passed in a String. I successfully initiated the class with `Class.forname()` but I can't cast `Class.getMethod("TableA", null)` to `Cursor`. Can anyone help me get cursors while I only have the `SQLiteOpenHelper Class` name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a common base class (or interface) for all your classes, then you can directly cast your new object to that type and access its members directly.

Comment: Thanks man although I didn't use this method but it's very helpful. I'll post my alternative as well

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found an other alternative for my problem. If all your databases have the same structure e.g. same tables but different data. You can have only one ***SQLiteOpenHelper*** class and pass database name to the class itself instead of defining it as static final. See code below

```
public class MyDatabases extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public ReadableDatabase (Context context, String Name) {super(context, Name, null, 1);}
}
```